# Port forwarding on a Jio router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a Jio Fiber Router an I want to enable port forwarding on it
I have set my Port Forwarding setting

But it does not work

Here are some images

[image: Port Forwarding Settings]

[image: Custom Services]

My firewall is set to Allow Always with any services

And bridging is on ,on port 3 vlan id 7

Comment: I's double NAT i Guess?

Comment: Can you check whether it is double NAT, then? Does your router show its "WAN" IP address?

Comment: IPv4 Primary DNS
49.45.0.3

Comment: That's the DNS server's address; it's not relevant to the problem. What is _your_ (i.e. your router's) address? The router must show it _somewhere._

Comment: IPv4 IP Address
10.203.184.105 / 255.255.248.0

Comment: You are behind CGNAT and do not receive a public IP. With current setup, port forwarding shall not work. Get a routable public IPv4 from your ISP to begin with.

Comment: Do i have to ask them?

Comment: now i change my IPv4 with 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the router's IPv4 is behind CGNAT in Jio Fiber so port forwarding won't work, but each client (device connected) has a static IPv6 address which you can check via ipconfig command.

You can configure AAAA record instead of A record in your domain's DNS and add the firewall rules (IPv6 Firewall Rules tab in your screenshot) to suit your requirements to access the device directly.

By doing this you need to run your own firewall in your device as all ports will be exposed to public internet.

Answer (score -1):

The router's IP is behind CGNAT ...

Therefore it can not be port forwarded ...

A routable IP is required which can cost additional 3$ - 11$
Depending on the ISP

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: Please dont add more information as an answer. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Actually that's kinda the answer. If he's behind CGN, port forwarding wouldn't allow access to systems behind his router.